# In sharepoint 2007 is there an easy way to add a large directory and all of it's contents?

Tags: 2007, file-upload

I am using windows 7 along with a sharepoint 2007 site. The sharepoint site has been newly implemented and is to replace a shared directory on a server.  That directory contains sub folders as well as their contents, the sharepoint site needs to mirror how they are set up on the windows server exactly.  Even though I can upload several files at once essentially moving them over subfolder by subfolder is tedious and time consuming where as in windows it would be a matter of just drag and drop/copy and paste then wait 30 seconds or so for them to transfer.  Is there any shortcut to move over this directory, its sub folders, as well as their contents?

I am aware that I may have to rename files to watch for unallowed characters as well as give the files new details and check them in.  Just looking for a quick way to move a large number of files over at once.

Thank you for your time,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can drag and drop files into a document library within a SharePoint site by using 'Explorer View'.

In the Document Library, go to Actions > Open with Explorer View

Keep in mind that since SharePoint relies upon addresses for each of the documents contained within, you may find and documents buried within heavily nested folders inaccessible in older browsers. This is because up until recently, there was a 255 character limit on any URL.